# Is there a way of changing the public "502 error" page on Google Cloud?

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Using a flex environment in GCP for deploying a Spring Boot application.

There are a couple of instances where I've legitimately had to take down the site while I do some maintenance. Customers should see something friendlier in these instances, eg "Hola, back with you in a second, we're just doing some essential maintenance".

Any idea where such an option would be, is it some additional stuff in the app.yaml?

Comment: Feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199480697

Answer (score 1):

You can just deploy a different version that shows a nice error page while you update the main app.

Comment: Have you seen how long it can take some deployment jobs to run? :) particularly as you start adding instances ...

Comment: Once you've deployed a maintenance version, you can leave it there and migrate your instances to it as needed when you are doing maintenance.  Migration takes about 20 seconds I think.

Answer (score 1):

The error "502" on Google App Engine is handled by Google front end and is not possible to replace for a custom page.